# Set Multiple Properties Simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

Is there any way to set multiple properties simultaneously? I tried this:

```
dateTextField.font, nameTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Book" size:16];
```

But that got a warning. Is there something else I could do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about just `dateTextField.font = nameTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Book" size:16];`??

Comment: Whaaaat! I had no idea you could do that! +1

Answer (score 0):

You definitely cannot do that.
Consider using a loop or just assign the font twice.

```
UIFont * font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Book" size:16];
dateTextField.font = font;
nameTextField.font = font;
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I lied: [multiple assignment exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097339/is-multiple-assignment-a-hack-in-obj-c) in Objective-C, but please don't use it as it may lead to unexpected behavior and terrible code to maintain.

Comment: Ok, how would you loop a font assignment?